# How to Create our own language package in django

Tags: python, django, localization

Django did lot for local languages but it doesnt provide support to all the languages. I just want to create my own language support in django.

Comment: Are you trying to localize Django itself (the admin interface etc) or your own project? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine, EN were not in Django locale.

in settings.py

```
from django.conf import global_settings

gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
   ('en', gettext('English')),
)

NEW_LANG_INFO = {
    'en': {
       'bidi': False, # right-to-left
       'code': 'en',
       'name': 'English',
       'name_local': u'English', #unicode codepoints here if necessary
    },
}

import django.conf.locale
LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO.items() + NEW_LANG_INFO.items())
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO
```

then

```
manage.py makemessages -l en
manage.py compilemessages
```

you see here which languages are supported by Django. [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/**init**.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/__init__.py)